# Basic Question: I have media info app installed on my mac M1 but there's no CLI

Tags: mediainfo

as stated in the subject, I have purchased the mediainfo app from App Store but there's no CLI available. Please advise. I am on Apple M1

Answer (score 0):

The MediaInfo app on the Mac App Store is the graphical interface version. You can download the MediaInfo command line version on [the dedicated download page](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfo/Download/Mac_OS).